# undefined reference to cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::PredefinedDictionaryType)

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, qt-creator, undefined-reference

I'm trying to make a program in Qt that receives an image from TCP and then finds an *ArUco* marker inside of it.

Everything works fine except for the *ArUco* library. Once I added a simple line defining a dictionary:

```cpp
cv::aruco::Dictionary ArucoDic = cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::DICT_4X4_50);
```

I get the error:

```
undefined reference to cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::PredefinedDictionaryType)
```

The other people I've found with this problem are able to solve it by adding the library in the *.pro* file, but I did that from the beginning following these tutorials:

- [OpenCV and Qt on Windows](https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_setup_Qt_and_openCV_on_Windows)
- [add contrib modules on OpenCV](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/4.x))

After all of that, my *.pro* file looks like this:

```js
QT -= gui
QT += network
QT += core

CONFIG += c++17 console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

# You can make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp \
        server.cpp

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target

HEADERS += \
    server.h

INCLUDEPATH += D:/OpenCV/opencv/release/install/include

LIBS += -LD:/OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib -lopencv_core480
LIBS += -LD:/OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib -lopencv_highgui480
LIBS += -LD:/OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib -lopencv_imgcodecs480
LIBS += -LD:/OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib -lopencv_imgproc480
LIBS += -LD:/OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib -lopencv_features2d480
LIBS += -LD:/OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib -lopencv_calib3d480
LIBS += -LD:/OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib -lopencv_aruco480
```

I don't really know what's the problem, since all libraries before *opencv_aruco480* work perfectly fine.

I also know Qt is reading the *ArUco* library, since it is able to predict the functions I'm writing. It just isn't compiling.

Comment: IDE being capable of autocompletion is ***independent*** of the compiler having all the info. separate systems. -- got the right headers included too?

Comment: The headers in the source file are the following:
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/aruco.hpp>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by adding the objdetect.dll library.
I also changed the way all libraries were referenced in the .pro file.

win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib/ -llibopencv_core480.dll
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib/ -llibopencv_highgui480.dll
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib/ -llibopencv_imgcodecs480.dll
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib/ -llibopencv_imgproc480.dll
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib/ -llibopencv_features2d480.dll
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib/ -llibopencv_calib3d480.dll
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib/ -llibopencv_aruco480.dll
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib/ -llibopencv_dnn480.dll
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib/ -llibopencv_flann480.dll
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib/ -llibopencv_gapi480.dll
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib/ -llibopencv_ml480.dll
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib/ -llibopencv_objdetect480.dll
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib/ -llibopencv_photo480.dll
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib/ -llibopencv_stitching480.dll
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib/ -llibopencv_video480.dll
win32: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../OpenCV/opencv/release/install/x64/mingw/lib/ -llibopencv_videoio480.dll

INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../OpenCV/opencv/release/install/include
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../OpenCV/opencv/release/install/include